# How do you generate an image where each pixel is a random color in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, random, colors

I'm trying to make an image with a random color for each pixel then open a window to see the image.

```
import PIL, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw            
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter


im = Image.new("RGB", (300,300))

for r in range(0,300):
    for c in range(0,300):
        re = random.randint(0, 255)
        gr = random.randint(0, 255)
        bl = random.randint(0, 255)
        im[r][c]=[re,gr,bl]
im.show()

     14         bl = random.randint(0, 255)
---> 15         im[r][c]=[re,gr,bl]
     16 im.show()
TypeError: 'Image' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) to assemble the required array efficiently, in a single [logical line](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines).

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# numpy.random.randint returns an array of random integers
# from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive). i.e. low <= value < high

pixel_data = np.random.randint(
    low=0, 
    high=256,
    size=(300, 300, 3),
    dtype=np.uint8
)

image = Image.fromarray(pixel_data)
image.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Well written :) your answer is very clear and easy to understand thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

First create your numpy array and then put it into PIL

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from PIL import Image

array = np.array([[[randint(0, 255),randint(0, 255),randint(0, 255)]] for i in range(100)])
array =  np.reshape(array.astype('uint8'), (10, 10, 3))
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(array.astype('uint8')))

img.save('pil_color.png')
```

this worked for me [image: here is the picture]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PIL Image is an Image object, into which you can't simply inject those values to the specified pixel. Instead, convert to an array and then show it as PIL image.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("RGB", (300,300))
im = np.array(im)

for r in range(0,300):
    for c in range(0,300):
        re = random.randint(0, 255)
        gr = random.randint(0, 255)
        bl = random.randint(0, 255)
        im[r][c]=[re,gr,bl]
img = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')

img.show()
```